# Fit RDLC report to A4 page in C# winforms

Tags: c#, rdlc, page-size

I have a question about fitting rdlc report to A4 page after print, after printing out the report it fills only half of the page in portrait mode, I already changed report properties --> page size to A4.
Tried to enlarge the table inside the report but still no luck.

Shortly, how to fit a report to A4 page after print out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, just change to A3 page size if you want to print it on A4, then it will fit the paper after printing it.